# A map created with Object.create(null) has toString property

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I am reading Eloquent JavaScript (https://eloquentjavascript.net/), and in Chapter 6, Marjin Haverbeke suggests one way of creating our own version of a map is to use Object.create(null). The example given in the book is

> console.log("toString" in Object.create(null));
>       //null

I tried creating a map using this method. Here is what I did :

```
let ages = Object.create(null); 
ages = {Boris : 29, Liang : 22, > Julia : 62};
console.log("Do we know toString's age?", 'toString' in ages);
//returns true
```

I expect the last console.log to return false, but it gives true. Why is this? How do I use this idea to create a map that does not inherit the toString property?
Note : I am vaguely aware of the map datatype, but I am trying to figure this out for conceptual understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *reassigned* `ages` to an object literal, which does inherit `toString` properly. The object created via `Object.create(null)` no longer has any reference after the `ages` variable is reassigned. If you did not reassign `ages` and simply assigned it properties, it would not have the `toString` property, as you would expect:

```js
const ages = Object.create(null); 
Object.assign(ages, {Boris : 29, Liang : 22, Julia : 62});
console.log("Do we know toString's age?", 'toString' in ages);

// similarly:

const ages2 = Object.create(null);
ages2.Boris = 29;
ages2.Liang = 22;
ages2.Julia = 62;
console.log("Do we know toString's age?", 'toString' in ages);
```

Answer (score 2):

With the following line, you're recreating an object:

```
 ages = {Boris : 29, Liang : 22, > Julia : 62};
```

What you wanna do is the following I suppose:

```
 ages = Object.create(null); 
 ages.Boris = 29;
 ages.Liang = 22;
 ages.Julia = 62;
 console.log("Do we know toString's age?", 'toString' in ages); // => false
```

Regards,
Vincent